# Android alertdialog theme

Tags: android, themes, styles, android-alertdialog

iv tried several diffrent ways but cant seem to get the alertdialog to properly change themes. my activities have there custom theme set in the manifest so im not sure if this is causing the conflict.

im using :

AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,R.style.DialogStyle)).create();

and im using the follwing style:

```
  <style name="DialogStyle" parent="android:Theme" >    
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background2</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#014076</item>       
</style>
```

it only changes certain text colours. all the titles and messages are all still default white colours and the background doesnt change either.

any help please.

Comment: yes, i want the background colour and text to be diffrent and not the default set onces by android.

Comment: you have text formatting files. If Yes then i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to gingerbread, 2.3.X, you can't.
It explicitly sets the theme in the constructor of the dialog, but in gingerbread you can supply it.